# VS Code 2017 "Localhost refused to connect" HTML file

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

This is a simple index.Html file, when i click on run i get the attached screen.

I have included the Json configuration.

The previous posts did not resolve my issue, and i did restart the machine as well as running VS Code as an admin. [VS Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwwdj.jpg)

[installed Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srwwa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happening because of your firewall setting restriction. please

1. **Try Live Server Extension AND check for Firewall Settings**.
2. **Plain HTML/CSS can be opened as a file, no need to run them through a web server.**

And if these procedures didn't work tell me about your browser.

Comment: " Live Server Extension"   installed and restarted VS Code..........

.......As well as Firewall setting, VS Code is allowed in Private networks.

Still same error.

Comment: What info about my browser should i supply you with?

Comment: What browser did you try **Chrome** or **Firefox**?

Comment: Chrome ..................
Configuration is included in the first image i attached  ..............
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwwdj.jpg

Comment: I think i resolved it......

...............it was the localhost port that needed correction from 8080 to 5500.